# Sale of products with correlated prices

Tags: cross-correlation

I have Buyer/Seller Problem I need to solve:

Me, as the buyer, wants to buy (lets say) 50 goods. There are several sellers who have all (or at least some) products I need  at stock. I can ask them for the price of the different products and choose the cheapest option. So far so good. The problem is the following: The products price is correlated if I combine different products:

Seller A can sell me Product A for 400$, Product B for 300, but both together for 500$.

I don't know how this correlation function is build, I can only ask for a result. I can even ask for parts:

I can ask for 10 items of Product A and 5 from Product B from Seller 1 and 5 items of Product A and 10 from Product B from Seller 2.

I can't ask for every possible combination, for 50 different items of different quantities with 10 sellers to ask for every possible combination (the brute force possibility) would last until the universum ends.

Is there an established best practice, like some sort of auction, to reach some kind of pareto optimum in acceptable time? Or can someone nudge me in a direction where such problems are solved so I can start researching myself (science papers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume there's a function that represents the price of A and the price of B.  Anytime you put in an order, both A and B react accordingly.  If you were given some assumptions, it would make the problem much simpler because at the moment it's going to end in a covariance matrix that you're trying to guess at with your trials.  (all that matrix basically tells you is exactly what I said...how the two products relate to each other with respect to input)

If you knew in buying 10 of an item that you had to pay the marginally increase cost of each...i.e. buying 1 at a time costs as much as 10 at once instead of getting a discount for 10 at once, it gives you a better idea of what the model is.  This might just be a problem you have to play with and study the reaction...I don't know if this is a statistics problem for you or what, but it could be just simple economics or complicated statistics.